# HDDs after format

Tags: hard-drive

What happen to our hard disks after formatting the partition with quick format option, from the electronics view? Is it possible to recover formatted data, are software solutions good enough to guarantee that all recovered data will be like before formatting? Is there a electronic solution to improve data recovery?

Comment: To many questions with some not making sense.  "Formatted data" is unclear, and so is why you need to "recover" it.  Recover after what occurance?  After formatting, there is no data to recover.

Comment: Recover data after quick format of NTFS partition.

Comment: After a quick format, you are likely to find the majority of the files when using tools like photorec and other similar tools. This is because you do not write the entire disk during a quick format, but only specific parts that hold filesystem (meta) information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format: only affects the data (ones and zeros) on the storage medium, electronics only deal with ones and zeros so when you format a number of ones and zeros are written somewhere on the disk. That's it.
Recovery: it depends a quick format does not erase data so it might be recovered. A full format/wipe: no recovery possible
If you want guaranteed recovery: DO NOT FORMAT
No electronic solutions to improve recovery exist.

Comment: Recovery from a single wipe may be possible with special equipment.

Comment: Indeed "may be possible". However, I have not heard/read that  someone has actually done this (recover after single wipe) successfully. So in my opinion it is a myth that this can be done. But I might be wrong, please tell me if I am :-)

Comment: It looks like it *used* to be possible, but now definitely isn't: http://www.vidarholen.net/~vidar/overwriting_hard_drive_data.pdf versus the older https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/sec96/full_papers/gutmann/index.html